# Reading comments in XML API response

Tags: php, xml, api, xpath

I have the following response from a XML api , I want to display the text that is placed in the comments section .

```
<OTA_AirDetailsRS PrimaryLangID="eng" Version="1.0" TransactionIdentifier=""><Errors><Error Type="ERR" FLSErrorCode="-10" FLSErrorName="Invalid Input"/></Errors><!-- Reason for error: The Date parameter is not valid [2014-05-16] --></OTA_AirDetailsRS>
```

I have used this :
...

```
$query = curl_exec($curl_handle);
curl_close($curl_handle);
$xml = new SimpleXmlElement($query);

if($xml->Errors){
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadXML($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
foreach ($xpath->query('//comment()') as $comment)
{
    var_dump($comment->textContent);
}
```

Its not displaying anything in this case , but if instead of passing xml response , I pass it a simple xml in string format , it is working . Please suggest if something is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to load the XML, not the object from your SimpleXmlElement call:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadXML($query);
```

Then your script outputs:

> string(64) " Reason for error: The Date parameter is not valid [2014-05-16] "